# Windows phone app link

Tags: browser, hyperlink, windows-phone

So - I want to make a windows phone app that links to my webpage when I open it - how do i do that? I have the SDK, and tried with the browser, but I can't seem to find anyway to set a homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the WebBrowser control, placing it on an otherwise empty page.  This may allow you to fine tune the experience if wish.

But what would be even easier is to just use the **WebBrowserTask**.  This would launch you right back out of your app and into OS's true browser experience.  In the App.xaml.cs file, just add the following code:

```
private void PhoneApplicationService_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();

    webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://my.superawesomewebsite.com", UriKind.Absolute);

    webBrowserTask.Show();
}
```

You app will immediately launch the browser an you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Not sure if you'd be able to help but someone has just referenced this answer saying they have seen an error and are not sure what they are doing wrong - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740710/create-an-application-link-on-windows-phone-8-1